# What do the 2 pins on the back of the Nexus S do?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, hardware

I'm really frustrated with a Nexus S turning off while in my pocket. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the pin positions, or these 2 strange back pins and contacts on the cover that don't seem to do anything:

[image: what are these pins for?]

I guess those tell the phone "the back cover is on", which must mean something to the phone.  When I put a piece of paper between those pins and the back cover, the phone at least doesn't seem to do the (literal 5 minute) "flash disk check" when the phone comes on.

Is blocking these pins from contacting a bad thing? Will it help to stop the phone from turning off in my pocket?

Comment: GPS antenna, maybe?

Comment: NFC, see my answer :)

Comment: @jlehenbauer I was going to say that first and then I questioned whether the N1 had NFC.  Should have searched :P

Comment: @MatthewRead haha I guess good thing I paid more attention to the picture, I guessed I assumed he was talking about an S from the picture, as I've seen the inside a million times now (my brother has the Nexus S and the battery falls out all the time). Ignorace wins, in this case! But thanks to eldarerathis for the edits too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is for the NFC functionality. Those contacts are used to transmit the info to and from the receiver/transmitter on the back cover (seen below outlined in green, though you probably guessed it :) ). They have to put it on the back cover because NFC only works for [usually no more than a few centimetres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication), and they need a way to feed the information back to the phone system itself.

It is discussed more in [this post](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-nexus/477167-seidio-3800mah-extended-battery.html#post3760640) on another Android forum.

[image: NFC transmitter]

Comment: [iFixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus-S-Teardown/4365/1#.T9t4YitYtYQ) also confirms this, as they discuss removing the NFC module from the back cover.

Comment: The NFC sticker is simply a flat coil acting as an antenna. Its size is a given. It's stuck onto the inner side of the back cover so nothing is in the way to interfere transmissions between the antenna and an NFC device hold tight to the back (the cover's plastic doesn't count).